# How to do nothing when close laptop and reopen?

Tags: wireless

I use ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Whenever I close my laptop it will disconnect my wireless connection.

Why is this happening?

I want my laptop do nothing when closing and reopening.

Or just only close monitor is also fine.

Is there any way to make it act this way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be trying to suspend the laptop.  Open the power settings and make sure the operation for "close lid" is set to "do nothing".

In System Settings in the hardware section, click on the power settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to go in to System Settings, then Power and change the 'When Lid Is Closed' option from 'Suspend' to 'Do Nothing' as pictured below.

[image]